# What is default location for apache kafka application logs

Tags: apache-kafka, log4j

I understand, two type of logs in apache kafka

1. For storing all topic's actual messages,
   which is configured via log.dirs property in kafka/config/server.properties
   if not specifies, kafka takes as /tmp/kafka-logs as default dir
2. Storing all kafka internal application logs, info, error, debug.
   Which is configured via -Dkafka.logs.dir=/some/path , JVM args while starting kafka.
   which is then used by log4j.properties to create different types of log files like controller.log etc

My question is, if we have missed to set application log directory(i.e kafka.logs.dir) during kafka startup, what is the default application directory used by kafka ?

Comment: in one setup i found application logs being at ./kafka/logs/

Comment: log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/server.log
Some reason, I cant see server.log, under kafka/logs, I can see other logs like controller.log etc but not server.log, any reasons ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it to be under , 
$kafka_Home/kafka/logs/
I guess, it was very obvious, i went unnecessarily in to too much of details

Answer (score 1):

[`kafka-run-class.sh`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/1d8f79964e9578f3769fd13c2535988bfc803696/bin/kafka-run-class.sh) has the following code:

```bash
base_dir=$(dirname $0)/..
```

```bash
# Log directory to use
if [ "x$LOG_DIR" = "x" ]; then
  LOG_DIR="$base_dir/logs"
fi
```

```bash
KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS="-Dkafka.logs.dir=$LOG_DIR $KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS"
```

So it will use the `LOG_DIR` environment variable, if it is set. Otherwise, it will be the `logs` directory that is a sibling to the `bin` directory containing the script you are running.